# How to send notification in android when a row is added to the database?

Tags: android, database

I am using Google App engine for the database. My idea is that whenever someone, for an instance, signs up for the app - then all users must get a notification that a new member has been added. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you should read about GCM. GCM provides a simple way through which you can send notification to your users through your server. You can read about GCM here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Does GCM not says that we need to have some registered users who can push notifications to other devices?

Comment: Yes it is so, let me take you through this. By registered user they mean that you should have a token number for each user so that they can be found. The process in sending message through GCM is : First you send the text which should be displayed as notification to the GCM server of Google. From there this message will be sent to the your user. But for google server to know who are your user it needs a token no, this token no is generated by google server only. So whenever you are making new account first you will generate a token no for that user and continued...

Comment: ... save it in your database and then use that token no for further use. This site also explain GCM in a very nice way and also show steps how you can implement it                               http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/                                             Hope you understand it...Please mark the answer if you find it helpful.. And feel free to ask doubts :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Gaurav for the answer, its really helpful.

Comment: Actually I am new to SO, hence can not mark it up... :(